# Use ignore_unavailable parameter in ElasticSearch Java client

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch java client as a Maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am doing search with multi-index, and I'm getting `IndexMissingException` and I want to ignore it using the parameter: '**ignore_unavailable**' but I don't know how to use it, and don't found documentation about this.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html (link about ignore_unavailable)

I'm creating the search like this:

```
    SearchRequestBuilder srb = ess.getClient()
        .prepareSearch(generateIndex(query)) //generateIndex returns a array
        .setTypes("mytype")
        .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_AND_FETCH)
        .setPostFilter(FilterBuilders.rangeFilter("Time")
                .from(time1.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC))
                .to(time2.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC))
        )   
        .setFrom(0).setSize(RESULT_MAX).setExplain(true)
        //putHeader don't work...
       .putHeader("ignore_unavailable", true);
```

**How do I use ignore_unavalilable here?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `setIndicesOptions(IndicesOptions)` - eg.

```
.prepareSearch(generateIndex(query))
.setIndicesOptions(IndicesOptions.fromOptions(true, false, false, false))
```

You could also use `IndicesOptions.lenientExpandOpen()` instead of calling `fromOptions()`.

Comment: can you please provide some context, as to where can I set the indices options globally? in my case, elasticsearch is configured automatically with application.properties, so there is no other config file

Comment: These are query-time options, telling the searcher to ignore any indices that are missing. It's not a global application-level setting. 

Bear in mind this answer is quite old now, the answer from @Shivam below may be more useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

In older versions of ES, we can use -

```
esClient.prepareSearch(allIndices)
        .setIndicesOptions(IndicesOptions.lenientExpandOpen())
```

In newer versions -

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(indices, searchSourceBuilder);
searchRequest.indicesOptions(IndicesOptions.lenientExpandOpen());
```